# How to assign variables to an aliased Controller inside a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

(*Disclaimer:* I don't really know if this question fits the Stackoverflow definition of 'question', since I already have (more than) one solution for the problem, I just don't *like* the solutions I've found. I apologize in advance if it happens to be so, and welcome alternatives.)

I'm creating an Angularjs Directive and I'd like to use the `Controller as ctrl` syntax so that I can have `ctrl.property` in my HTML, instead of a non-contextual, possibily-shadowing `property`.

However, this implies that, on the Controller function, variables to be accessed in the HTML need to be bound to `this`. For example:

```html
<!-- HTML file: greetings.html -->
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in main.items track by $index" ng-bind="item"></li>
</ul>
```

```js
angular.module('GreetingModule').directive('greetings', function() {
  'use strict;'
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'greetings.html',
    controller: function () {
      this.greetings = ['Hello', 'Hola', 'Salut'];
    },
    controllerAs: main
  }
});
```

I'm very okay with this. But things fall apart when I start to use functions.

Let's say I need to load the greetings from a service.

```js
angular.module('GreetingModule').directive('greetings',
    ['langService', function(langService) {
  'use strict;'
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'greetings.html',
    controller: function () {
      this.greetings = [];

      function languagesLoaded(langs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
          this.greetings.push(langs[i].greeting);
        }
      }

      langService.load({
        callback: languagesLoaded
      });
    },
    controllerAs: 'main'
  };
}]);
```

This will fail. At the time of the callback, when `languagesLoaded` is called, `this` is not bound and the function will throw an error, `this.greetings is undefined`.

I've found three ways around this, but I dislike all three (I don't really have any technical reason for disliking them, they just *feel* wrong, like I'm trying to do something I'm not supposed to):

1. Create a variable pointing to `this` and use that in the function:

```js
    var self = this;
    // ...
    self.greetings.push(langs[i].greeting);
```

2. Passing `this` in the object argument to `langService.load()`:

```js
    /* In the directive */
    langService.load({
      target: this,
      callback: languagesLoaded
    })

    /* In the service */
    function load(config) {
      // load languages, then:
      config.languagesLoaded.call(target, languages);
    }
```

3. Binding the array both to `this` and to the function scope, so that changing the scope variable also affects the `this` variable (since they reference the same array):

```js
    var greetings = this.greetings = [];
    // ...
    greetings.push(langs[i].greeting);
```

Is there any other way around this? Assuming there isn't one, which of the above solutions would be the most correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the function's `this` to the controller:

```
langService.load({
  callback: languagesLoaded.bind(this)
});
```

For IE < 9 a polyfill would be needed because `bind` is available as of ECMAScript 5.

Comment: This actually seems much better, thank you. I'm going to wait a bit to see if someone has anything else to say/add. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'll write it anyway as a reference. Angular features `angular.bind`, which does the same thing ad ES5, but works also on older browsers.

Comment: @link Good catch. I wasn't aware of that function. Alas, Angular itself doesn't run on older browsers as of 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Your **approach #1** seems the best. You should be careful when using `this` since it changes its meaning based on its context, for example, like in a function. Sometimes you wouldn't even know this, if you are using a 3rd party library.

I find this [guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controlleras-with-vm) useful. From the guide:

```
function Customer() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.name = {};
    vm.sendMessage = function() { };
}
```