# In AngularJS, when using "controller as" syntax and "this", how to reference "this" inside a promise's callback?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, promise

I have some data being returned inside a then(), which I need to get stored inside the "this" variable. Since it's not being stored inside the scope, and since it's wrapped inside a callback, my controller's "this" is not valid. How can I bubble the data back up so it can be stored inside "this"? See below:

```
angular.module('logisticsApp.controllers').
controller('InventoryCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'DataService', 
    function ($scope, $http, $window, DataService) {

    this.inventory = ''; // need to have data stored here

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', angular.bind(this, function() {
      // "this" is still valid here
      myService.getInventory().then(function(data) {
        // "this" is no longer valid!
        $scope.inventory = data; // so this fails
      });
    }));
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign variables to an aliased Controller inside a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822784/how-to-assign-variables-to-an-aliased-controller-inside-a-function)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `angular.bind`:

```
myService.getInventory().then(angular.bind(this, function(data) {
  console.log(this.inventory);
}));
```

From [angular.bind docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind):

> Returns a function which calls function fn bound to self (self becomes the **this** for fn).

---

You can also save a reference to the context(this) like so:

```
var self = this;

myService.getInventory().then(function(data) {
  console.log(self.inventory);
});
```